# Python - Removing a space from a print function

Tags: python

Currently, I'm having an error, where

```
w = float(input("Enter weight(grams): "))
print (w/1000,'kg')
```

returns

```
Enter weight(grams): 3000
3.0 kg
```

When attempting to convert from grams to kg in something. Problem is the space between the 3.0 and the kg which I cannot seem to find an answer for. I really dislike the spacing default within the print function and .strip() doesn't seem to be working for me.

My desired result is

```
Enter weight(grams): 3000
3.0kg
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's because when you give multiple values to the [print()](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html?highlight=print#print) function, it seperates all the expressions with space. You should use a string format instead:

```
>>> w = 3000
>>> print ("{}{}".format(w/1000, 'kg'))
3.0kg
```

Another, less clean way to do it, is to give the `sep` parameter to `print()` so it's set no nothing instead of the default space:

```
>>> w = 3000
>>> print (w/1000, 'kg', sep='')
3.0kg
```

But always prefer the string format, it's more flexible and powerful.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify a seperator for the print function.

```
>>> print("Hello", "World", sep='')
HelloWorld
```